# How do I convert several web pages into one pdf document?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public FileResult Download() 
{ 

    var doc = new EO.Pdf.PdfDocument(); 
    EO.Pdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl("http://www.google.com/", doc); 

    var ms = new MemoryStream();     
    doc.Save(ms); 

    ms.Position = 0; 

    return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf") 
               { 
                   FileDownloadName = "download.pdf"
               }; 
}
```

Can you please show if possible, how to extend the code above to be able to convert several web pages into one pdf document?

The tricky part is that we don't know what pages a user is likely to attempt to convert.

So, hardcoding the webpages as the code above shows isn't helping us.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
//Create a new PdfDocument object
var doc = new EO.Pdf.PdfDocument();

//Convert two ore more different pages into the same PdfDocument

EO.Pdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl("c:\\1.html", doc);

EO.Pdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl("c:\\2.html", doc);
```

Latest code:

```
public FileResult Download() 
{ 
    var doc = new EO.Pdf.PdfDocument(); 

foreach(var url in passedUrls)  
{ 
EO.Pdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(url, doc);   
doc.Save(ms);   
}


    ms.Position = 0; 

    return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf") 
               { 
                   FileDownloadName = "download.pdf"
               }; 
}
```

Latest from Adam (thank you sir)

```
public FileResult Download() 
{ 

var documents = new List<EO.Pdf.PdfDocument>(); 
foreach(var url in passedUrls) 
{ 
    var doc = new EO.Pdf.PdfDocument(); 
    EO.Pdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(url, doc); 
    documents.Add(doc); 
} 

EO.Pdf.PdfDocument mergedDocument = EO.Pdf.PdfDocument.Merge(documents.ToArray()); 
}
```

Hopefully, others find these codes useful.

Comment: What library is EO.Pdf.PdfDocument exist in?

Comment: Please use your question title to describe the problem / question.

Comment: jadarnel27, My apology if the title isn't consistent with question. I really am sorry about that.

Adam, eo.pdf is a  set of .net class from a company called  EssentialsObject.

Comment: No problems, just letting you know.  Just try and make your title more descriptive next time =)  Also, if you want to get the attention of someone who has commented on your question, use @ notifications (@jadarnel27 would notify me, for instance).

Comment: @jadarnel27, Oh wow, I didn't know that! Thanks for that useful info.

Do you know the answer to the question I asked Adam?

Comment: Also, if I have to notify Adam, for instance, do I use @Adam Smith or just @Adam?

Comment: See here: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: In your first code sample, you want replace `var doc = new EO.Pdf.PdfDocument();` with Adam's entire sample, basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Help documentation](http://www.essentialobjects.com/doc/4/eo.pdf.pdfdocument.merge_overloads.aspx) I would recommend the following:

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    var urls = new List<string>
    { // Populate list with urls
        "C:\\1.html",
        "C:\\2.html"
    };

    var documents = new List<EO.Pdf.PdfDocument>();
    foreach(var url in urls)
    {
        var doc = new EO.Pdf.PdfDocument();
        EO.Pdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(url, doc);
        documents.Add(doc);
    }

    EO.Pdf.PdfDocument mergedDocument = EO.Pdf.PdfDocument.Merge(documents.ToArray());

    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    mergedDocument.Save(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;

    return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf") { FileDownloadName = "download.pdf" };
}
```

Comment: Very,very nice of you Adam and truly much appreciated.

I have updated your code above so you can see if I followed you correctly. Also, can you please show how to use it sir?

Sorry if it is such a newbie question.

Comment: thank you so very much for your kindness sir.

I guess, I was wondering, how do I run it?

Thanks for your patience and sorry for continuing to bother you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Pass an array of url strings to the function

Then

```
foreach(var url in passedUrls) 
{
EO.Pdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(url, doc);  
doc.Save(ms);  
}
```

Comment: Vishal, many thanks for your prompt assistance. I have posted latest copy with your code included. Did I get it all together correctly?

Forgive me for another cheap question, how do I use this?